# Java List auto create and add

Tags: java, list, arraylist, null

Is it possible to replace this:

```
    if (archiveUnitEntity.getArchiveCaseEntityList() == null) {
      archiveUnitEntity.setArchiveCaseEntityList(new ArrayList<ArchiveCaseEntity>());
    }
    
    archiveUnitEntity.getArchiveCaseEntityList().add(archiveCaseEntity);
```

This something like that:

ifListNullCreate(archiveUnitEntity.getArchiveCaseEntityList()).Add(archiveCaseEntity);

Comment: It seems like a [singleton pattern](https://www.javaboss.it/singleton-design-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the method `getArchiveCaseEntityList()` then you could add that null check into the getter and update it there (or create another method if you need it to be null in some cases). If not, then you could create the method you want wherever you want/need.

But I don't think there is a built-in method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution.

In the `ArchiveUnitEntity` class, declare the list like this, so that it's not null on creation.

```
private List<ArchiveCaseEntity> archiveCaseEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You might also want to change the setter for that field, so that it can't get set to null.

```
public void setArchiveCaseEntityList(ArchiveCaseEntityList archiveCaseEntityList) {
    this.archiveCaseEntityList = archiveCaseEntityList == null ? new ArrayList<ArchiveCaseEntity>() : archiveCaseEntityList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to initialize your archiveCaseEntityList attribute during the creation of the instance of archiveUnitEntity. Avoiding null object can simplify a lot of things :)

Directly when you declare your attribute :

```java
private List<ArchiveCaseEntity> archiveCaseEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

or in constructor :

```java
public ArchiveUnitEntity(){
   this.archiveCaseEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And finally, you could build a new method to manage ArchiveCaseEntity addition :

```java
public void addArchiveCaseEntity(ArchiveCaseEntity entity){
   this.archiveCaseEntityList.add(entity);
}
```